# Can I delete the Health and Safety Information app?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

On my **Nintendo 3DS,** I am getting real annoyed when I try to press a game right next to it but accidentally press the **Health and Safety Information** icon. Is there any way to delete it permanently off the system? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to permanently delete this app.

You have a couple of options to avoid clicking it accidentally, though:

1. Place it in a folder. When you select an empty spot in your Home Screen, you can choose to create a folder. You can then place the Health and Safety Information, along with any other built-in app you don't want in a folder and never use them.
2. Drag it all the way to the right. If you hold your stylus on an icon for a few seconds, you can move them around. If you place the Health and Safety icon all the way to the right, you will most likely forget it's even there.
3. Combine the previous 2 options. Create a folder as in 1, then place that folder to the right as in 2. You'll be able to leave multiple unwanted icons off-screen while minimising the number of slots they take.

Answer (score 7):

You can't delete it completely, but you could try [putting it into a folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64023/how-do-i-create-folders), which would lessen the chances of you hitting it by accident.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot delete the Health and Safety Information app but you can move it. I put it in a folder under a bunch of miscellaneous apps that I generally don't use (like Camera) so it doesn't get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm answering insanely late, but, you sort of can, by homebrew, you can remove it, if you are on 9.2 or running a custom firmware

Comment: can you elaborate